# Find difference between two consecutive rows from a result in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch the difference in "Data" column between two consecutive rows. For example, need Row2-Row1 ( 1902.4-1899.66) , Row 3-Row 2 and so on. The difference should be stored in a new column.

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+----+
| Name      | Data       |meter|       Time             |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------+----+
| Boiler-1  |  1899.66   | 1   | 5/16/2019 12:00:00 AM  |
| Boiler-1  |  1902.4    | 1   | 5/16/2019  12:15:00 AM |
| Boiler-1  |  1908.1    | 1   | 5/16/2019  12:15:00 AM |
| Boiler-1  |  1911.7    | 6   | 5/16/2019  12:15:00 AM |
| Boiler-1  |  1926.4    | 6   | 5/16/2019  12:15:00 AM |
| 
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------------     +
```

Thing is the table structure that I have shown in the question, is actually obtained from two different tables. I mean, the above table is a result of a Select query to get data from two different tables. Goes like "select name, data, unitId, Timestamp from table t1 join table t2....." So is there anyway for me to calculate the difference in "data" column value between consecutive rows, without storing this above shown result into a table?

I use SQL 2008, so Lead/Lag functionality cannot be used.

Comment: If you don't have access to `LEAD`/`LAG` the "old" way to use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows, and then use a `LEFT JOIN` against itself on the value of the `ROW_NUMBER` +/- 1. Without your SQL, this is difficult to show you; so I suggest including it in your question. Also, SQL Server 2008 has less than 2 months left of support now, so you really need to consider your upgrade path sooner rather than later.

Comment: hint : use `cte`, `row_number()`, `self join`

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in SQL Server 2008 uses `apply` -- and it can be expensive:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*,
       (t.data - tprev.data) as diff
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.name = t.name and
            tprev.boiler = t.boiler and
            tprev.time < t.time
      order by tprev.time desc
     ) tprev;
```

This assumes that you want the previous row when the `name` and `boiler` are the same.  You can adjust the correlation clause if you have different groupings in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used this with some minor modification and it did the job. You saved me!

Comment: Hi, Once again thank you for this solution and it worked great. However, would you be able to explain the usage of **TOP** in `'select top (1) tprev.*'` ? Because, I unfortunately forgot to include Top keyword and all my results of value difference between consecutive rows turned out to be the same. It took me a while to include the top keyword and solve the issue. I understand that TOP is usually used to return a specified no. of rows, but here I am confused regarding its usage. As I am a beginner to this, would greatly appreciate any explanation that you may provide :)

Answer (score 1):

Not claiming that this is best, this is just another option in SQL SERVER < 2012. As from SQL Server 2012 its easy to do the same using LEAD and LAG default option added. Any way, for small and medium data set, you can consider this below script as well :)

**Note:** This is just an Idea for you.

```
WITH CTE(Name,Data)
AS
(
    SELECT 'Boiler-1' ,1899.66 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Boiler-1',1902.4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Boiler-1',1908.1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Boiler-1',1911.7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Boiler-1',1926.4
    --Replace above select statement with your query
)
SELECT A.Name,A.Data,A.Data-ISNULL(B.Data,0) AS [Diff] 
FROM
(
    --Adding ROW_NUMBER Over (SELECT NULL) will keep the natural order
    --of your data and will just add the row number.
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  RN  FROM CTE
)A
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  RN FROM CTE
) B 
--Here the JOINING will take place on curent and next row for using ( = B.RN-1)
ON A.RN = B.RN-1
```

Comment: thank you so much for explaining in detail. I will have a try with this :)